# Why is there a GRUB boot menu even though I have a single boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So, I was using Ubuntu in a dual boot mode with Windows 10 for about a month. Yesterday, I decided to make a complete shift to Ubuntu. So, I plugged in my boot flash drive and installed a fresh installation of Ubuntu and deleted the windows 10 partition by selecting the "Something else" option in the installation process.

Now, even though I just have Ubuntu in my system, I still get the GRUB boot menu every time.

Comment: I would have formatted the disk before installing Ubuntu if you wanted a clean install. In my experience, Windows 10 has at least three partitions and it also installs boot instructions in the EFI partition.  You may be able to delete the Microsoft related folders in the EFI partition and run `os-prober` and `upgrade-grub`. If this works for you let me know and I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I did format all the partitions containing windows 10 and ubuntu. However, I suppose there is a 552mb recovery partition that is installed in my Laptop by the manufacturer itself (It contains Windows 7 since I didn't get a recovery CD). Also, can you please guide me in a bit more detail on how to delete the boot instructions in EFI partition? Thanks.

Comment: Remove /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP & Windows entry in UEFI. Details: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem by deleting a partition using GParted. There was a partition labelled as 'msftres' which is a partition reserved for Microsoft Applications. You can delete it if you are not planning to use Windows.